# Function on blur event is not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two input text fields in a form. Both inputs are binded in a span.

I call a function on `onblur` event of both input fields which makes both inputs disappear.
When I enter a value in the first text field and then I click in second text field both input fields disappear.
I know that I have called the function on 'onblur' event but I want the user to click on at least second input field.

Comment: Can you show some code?? That will really help us to solve your issue.

Comment: please show your code...

Comment: Do you want to fire blur event on both input ?

Comment: @Dhaval. You're right, but it's pretty obvious what is his mistake, see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Your code probably looks like this:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
        $('input').hide();
    });
```

While you need this:

```
$('input').blur(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
```

Don't select all the textboxes inside the blur callback, hide only the one that was lost focus (use `this`).

Comment: Yeah, sorry kind of forgotten that sorry :D

Comment: @EvilP. _"The blur event is raised when an element loses focus"_

Answer (score 0):

Resuming that both of your input fields get blured you are not using ID's.
You could give both of your input fields ID's

```
<input id="firstInput" type="text"/>
<input id="secondInput" type="text"/>
```

and individually blur them on their own:

```
$('#firstInput').on("click",function(){
        $(this).hide();
};
$('#secondInput').on("click",function(){
        $(this).hide();
};
```

**NOTE:** `.on()` only works for jQuery 1.7+ . If you are using a lower version use `.bind()` or `.click()`

**EDIT:** As gdoron already mentioned in his code. You are probably targeting **every** `input` `$('input')`field with your `.hide()` but you should use `$(this).hide();` Which only hides the actual input field that lost focus.